# Subtraction of two numbers isn't stored in database

Tags: php, laravel

I have two numbers in my database which I want to subtract with `intval()` and `bcdiv` functions. I'm not sure why one of the numbers came as `string` the other one is `float`

This is var_dump of both numbers

```
number1: float(0.11037128) 
number2: string(10) "0.19902165"
```

Function which I'm trying to perform

```
$result = $number1 - $number2;

// var_dump($result) return float(-0.08865037)
$res->result = bcdiv(intval($number1 - $number2), 100000000, 8 ));

$res->save();
```

The column to which I want to store this result is DECIMAL(20,8).

There is no errors, nothing. Page is reload normally. Everything else got saved in database except this result.

I'm using Laravel framework and this is in my controller. Any ideas?

Comment: what is the output of `bcdiv()` using `var_dump()`?

Comment: @VaibhavrajRoham `var_dump(bcdiv($number1, $number2));` return `string(1) "0"` but I'm sure that `bcdiv()` is working properly because I'm using it on other pages.

Comment: For test-case give 2 numbers which will not return `0` by `bcdiv()`

Comment: Hm, `var_dump(bcdiv(5 , 2));` return `string(12) "2.5000000000"`. What does this mean.. I can't use it because the result is `0.xxxx`?

Comment: Are you getting a value of 0 stored to your database..?

Comment: Yes, `0.00000000` is stored in database

Comment: so, that is correct..! `bcdiv(intval($number1 - $number2), 100000000, 8 );  //  = 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing

```
$number1 =  0.11037128;
$number2 =  0.19902165;
$res->result = bcdiv(intval($number1 - $number2), 100000000, 8 ));
```

surely you are going to get `0.00000000` only.

As per the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php#refsect1-function.intval-examples) of `intval()`, It picks the integer value from number. So after `intval($number1 - $number2)` you are going to get `0` hence you will get `0.00000000` as `bcdiv()` output.

**Usecase I used**

```
$number1 =  10.11037128; // Changed this number
$number2 =  0.19902165;
var_dump(bcdiv(intval($number1 - $number2), 100000000, 8 ));
```

which gives output as

```
string(10) "0.00000009"
```

Refer [bcdiv docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcdiv.php) and [intval docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php).

**Edited**

If you have issues with numbers like getting string type etc. then try to typecast them as below.

```
$number1 = (float) 10.11037128;
$number2 = (float) 0.19902165;
```

Comment: So this isn't an issue but normal behavior of bcdiv? Didn't knew this. So i can just take difference like `$res->result = $number1 - $number2;` ? I mean do I need to worry about the length after delimiter and roundings .. etc?

Comment: Exactly! everything is right. And the point how you want to use is completely depend on your application and you.

Comment: I need to be rounded and saved with this length `0.XXXXXXXX` i.e. 8 symbols after delimiter. Will make few tests but seems is working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Operands of *bcdiv* excluding "scale" must be strings
Maybe it's a problem

http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcdiv.php

Comment: I've tried to turn float number into string using `strval()` function but still doesn't save the result into database.